# Is there a single word for an arbitrary closed curved line?

Tags: terminology

A circle is a circle. A triangle is a triangle. An ellipse is an ellipse. A square is a square. Is there a name for the general case of an arbitrarily formed line (so it can be curved) with the property that it is closed and continuous? Consider the line not to be a fractal one and not being differentiable at maximum a finite number of points only (like a triangle). Is there a single word for such a thing (like circle or triangle)?

Comment: [Closed curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Topological_curve)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write one word. I'll edit.

Comment: errr... Shape? Blob?

Comment: @TedWrigley A Clolisha! Or an Arcloculi... The day they met, Clolisha and Arcloculi laid entangled in each other's arms...

Comment: More particularly the image of a closed curve, an embedding of a circle (S1).  The minor ambiguity with "closed curve", is that it can matter how the thing is drawn, and which is intended is not always clear.  By specifying that you want the image or embedding, you are explicitly ignoring how the curve is drawn, and looking just at the resulting space occupied.